# OnSubmit event not fired with preventDefault on the container

Tags: reactjs

Would somebody explain to me why the submit callback is not called when I try to submit the form (using the button or by pressing enter) ?

The reason is this onClick event on the container but I cannot grasp why...

Shouldn't the submit event be caught by the form before bubbling up to the div with onClick?

```js
export default function App() {
  const [val, setVal] = useState("");
  function submit() {
    alert(val);
  }

  function prevent(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
  }

  return (
    <div className="App" onClick={prevent}>
      <form onSubmit={submit}>
        <input
          name="test"
          value={val}
          onChange={(e) => setVal(e.target.value)}
        />
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/stoic-keldysh-idkdg)

**Edit:**
My form is inside an 'a' tag and because of that, I wanted to use preventDefault so the user to not be redirected when filling up the form.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you are trying to achieve here, but preventing default actions on the parent element is not actually the best thing to do. Your code could have been better this way:

```
export default function App() {
  const [val, setVal] = useState("");
  function submit(e) {
     e.preventDefault();
     alert(val);
   }
 return (
    <form onSubmit={(e) => submit(e)}>
    <input
      name="test"
      value={val}
      onChange={(e) => setVal(e.target.value)}
    />
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
  </form>);
 }
```

The `prevent()` function is unnecessary and have no meaningful impacts on your code. Keeping it simple and sweet is the best way to go.

Comment: Thanks for the response!
My form is inside an 'a' tag and because of that, I wanted to use preventDefault so the user to not be redirected when filling up the form.
Probably I will rework it to not be nested inside an anchor.
I was just wondering why it is not working.

Comment: Is it important you have your form in an anchor tag? I believe React will issue you a warning on that approach.

Comment: No, it's not important so I'll rework it and do the navigation manually :)